# Connection string for entity framework to connect to SQL High Availability servers

Tags: .net, entity-framework, sql-server-2012, high-availability, alwayson

I am developing an application using Entity Framework. In this application, the target database is a SQL 2012 High Availability Cluster Servers which has two members. One configured as primary, and the other as secondary.

Trying to connect to the cluster using SQL Management Studio is fine. I could do query's and everything. The issue is when I try to connect it with my application. It will throw an exception with the message:

```
The target database ('UserDatabase') is in an availability group and is currently accessible for connections when the application intent is set to read only. For more information about application intent, see SQL Server Books Online.
```

Checking more, the exception is thrown when the Entity Framework is trying to Open a connection to the database.

Here is the connection string I am using:

```
data source=SQLCL01;initial catalog=UserDatabase;user id=test-user;password=##pass##;MultipleActiveResultSets=True
```

Since I know I could connect with the same credential perfectly using SQL Management Studio, I was wondering if the issue is with my connection string. Does anyone have similar experiences?

Update:
SQLCL01 is a listener. The DB instance name is SQLDB01 & SQLDB02

Answer (score 1):

I believe SQLCL01 at the time you tried to connect is running as a secondary role. In order to connect to a secondary replica you need that the AG is configured to allow readable secondary replicas connection and your connection string must explicitly state that the connection has a read-only intention by adding: `ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly`

Alternatively you can use a listener name in the 'data source'. This is a network name that is always pointing to the current primary. This needs to be setup in the AG. For more information, check:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213417.aspx

Comment: Actually, SQLCL01 is a listener. The database name is both: SQLDB01 and SQLDB02, so yeah that is a listener.

Comment: What happens if you add ApplicationIntent to the connection string?

Comment: By adding: ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly I could access the application, but there would be another exception from Entity Framework since I am using it to write also.

Comment: then try ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite

Answer (score 0):

Try Using:

```
<b>server=tcp:</b>SQLCL01;initial catalog=UserDatabase;user id=test-user;password=##pass##;MultipleActiveResultSets=True
```